# How does Loader work with two parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-fullstack

I'm trying to learn how to use Loaders in React-router-dom and can't get two parameters working.

```
export const loadConvoMsg = ({conversationId, courseId}) => async () => {
    console.log('convoIDLoad', conversationId)
    console.log('courseIdLoad', courseId)
    if (conversationId) {
        console.log('conversationId type', typeof conversationId)
        const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/conversation/${conversationId}`);
        // const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/conversation/1`);
        console.log('hello')
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    }
    else if (courseId) {
        console.log('courseId in loader', courseId)
        console.log('conversationId in loader', conversationId)
        const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/course/${courseId}`);
        // const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/course/1`);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
```

From Loader.js

I tried a combination of calls in sidebar.js which imports loadConvoMsg from Loader.js

const convos = useLoaderData(loadConvoMsg({ courseId: 1, conversationId: '' })());
cons convos = useLoaderData(loadConvoMsg, {courseid: 1, conversationId: ''})

then in App.js

```
        <Route path="chat" element={<Chat />} loader={loadConvoMsg} />
        <Route path='/chat/conversation/:pageId' element={<Chat />} loader={loadConvoMsg} />
```

where sidebar is in chat.js

const convos = useLoaderData(loadConvoMsg({ courseId: 1, conversationId: '' })());

result: console.log(convos) => a function of async

Other calls did the same or gave me null because the parameters were undefined.

There are no issues in the backend as I am able to get/post just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a misunderstanding of how the new react-router v6 loader works.

The loader function is intended to facilitate data loading process and reduce boilerplate code. It must be `asynchronous` itself (not returning another `async` function as in your code). Also, the loader function has two parameters, `request` and `params`.

Here's an example of how to use it properly:

```
export const loadConvoMsg => async ({params}) => {
    console.log('convoIDLoad', params.conversationId)
    console.log('courseIdLoad', params.courseId)
    ...
    return data;
}
```

Next, you can access `loader` data by using the `useLoaderData()` hook without passing any data to the hook. This should resolve your problem.